# Quickblox - How to join objects into one query

Tags: quickblox

I got a question about this answer.

"At the moment QuickBlox doesn't provide 'JOIN' like operator in CustomObjects module. You should do 2 separate queries.

Instead of implementing JOIN query we are going to provide ability to upload queries code to server, so server will return result off all your scripts.

At the moment you can do 2 separate queries: - request all messages - choose user_ids and request users by users ids"

Does QuickBlox provide 'JOIN' like operator in CustomObjects for now?
Is there ability to upload queries code to server for now?

I don't want to do 2 separated queries, because i've too many ID's for second query and got an error "414 Request URI too long".

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it now,

so you have to do 2 separate requests